# using in clause inside jpa query gives Operand should contain 1 column(s) error

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

i'm trying to use `in` clause inside a jpa query but it gives  `Operand should contain 1 column(s)` error.

Here is my query:

```
@Query(value = "select e from Table e where " +
            "((:plantId is null and :unitId is null and :functionalLocationId is null) or" +
            " (:functionalLocationId is not null and e.functionalLocation.id in (select f.id from FunctionalLocation f where f.id = :functionalLocationId)) or" +
            " (:unitId is not null and :functionalLocationId is null and e.functionalLocation.unit.id in (select u.id from Unit u where u.id = :unitId)) or" +
            " (:plantId is not null and :unitId is null and :functionalLocationId is null and e.functionalLocation.unit.plant.id in (select p.id from Plant p where p.id = :plantId))) and" +
            "((:equipmentTagNumbers) is null or e.tagNo in (:equipmentTagNumbers)) and" +
            "(:startDate is null or e.lastUpdateDate >= :startDate) and" +
            "(:endDate is null or e.lastUpdateDate <= :endDate)" +
            "order by e.id desc")
```

`:equipmentTagNumbers` property is a `Lis<String>` and if i send null for it query works as i expected but when i send actual data it gives the error.

any suggestions?

Comment: Your query has some subquery which returns more than 1 coulmns where you expect only 1 column, Such as,

"where x = (select x,y from abr)"

Comment: try to add the jpa query call in which you form the query and set the params

Comment: @MaciejKowalski i tried but result is the same

Comment: @kyur are you using eclipselink as your JPA implementation? Just experienced the same issue and according to my team mates this is a bug in our eclipselink version (also see http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/119934-in-clause-not-working-for-jpa-eclipselink-repository-mysql-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((:equipmentTagNumbers) is null or...
```

becomes

```
(1,2,4 is null or...
```

which is not proper SQL.

Instead, go like this:

```
@Query(value = "select e from Table e where " +
        "..." +
        (equipmentTagNumbers == null ? "" : "e.tagNo in (:equipmentTagNumbers)) and ") +
        "..." +
        "order by e.id desc")
```

That way equipmentTagNumbers does not affect the query when it is null.

Comment: i dont think that will work because ```equipmentTagNumbers``` property is filled in run time. so i cannot check if its null or not.

Comment: It makes no sense to me why this is the accepted answer.  The `equipmentTagNumbers` isn't available at compile-time in an `@Query` annotation.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i understood there is no `isEmpty` or `length` in jpa queries if your parameter is an `array` like in this case. @SOlsson was right `(1,2,4 is null or...` is not valid Sql so i decided to add an extra parameter to my query in order to check if its `null` or not so my last query like:

```
        ...
            "((:hasEquipmentNumbers) is null or e.tagNo in (:equipmentTagNumbers)) and" 
        ...
```

`:hasEquipmentNumbers` is a Boolean which i can assign `null` so if its null then nobody hurts and if its not i can run my `IN` clause with no trouble.

PS:I marked his answer cuz, it seemingly like an answer. But i implemented like i explain.